# O que é um código legado?

Tags: terminologia, independente-de-linguagem

Eu já ouvi esse termo da boca de algumas pessoas, mas não costumo ser bom com esses termos técnicos.

O que seria um *código legado*?

Está relacionado ao código ser ultrapassado?

Comment: Maior porcentagem de perguntas são relacionadas a problemas que  na internet já existe uma solução,  mais vejo perguntas simples como "Preciso de ajuda no comando IF" que ficam abertas e não recebem nenhum voto para serem fechadas, está sua pergunta e fácil de ser localiza na internet e mesmo assim recebeu 49 votos, queria entender qual o critério você usa para julgar uma pergunta ser fechada sem adicionar nenhuma justificativa.

Comment: Olá @Harry. Não somos um site de helpdesk, um nivel de helpdesk é até tolerado, desde que não caia nos problemas citados no [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/3635), voltando ao foco, o principal objetivo do stackoverflow é ser um repositório de conhecimentos, essa explicação do que "é legado" pode existir em outros sites, mas o publico do stack overflow **pode e deve ter o direito** de procurar dentro do próprio site a resposta com um texto que seja avaliado por membros para ser uma fonte de confiança que as informações estejam corretas. Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: Olá, se você tem algum questionamento, reclamação ou dúvida sobre o funcionamento da comunidade, sugiro que faça uma pergunta no  [meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/). A maioria de perguntas como "preciso de ajuda no if" eu fecho (e os demais moderadores também). Lembrando que aqui é um site de pergunta e resposta sobre programação, e não um fórum. Sobre a questão de ser "simples" ou não: [você pode ler mais sobre isso aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/%c3%89-errado-perguntar-por-coisas-que-se-acham-facilmente-como-alguns-julgam-no-go)

Comment: Sobre a pergunta ser fechada: As justificativas estão sempre destacadas na própria descrição do fechamento. Sobre a questão do votos: é a comunidade que decide como votam ou não nas perguntas (eu mesmo não posso votar em mim).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu entendo o seu ponto de vista, mais se eu for pegar questões que existem na internet, como você falou o publico deve ter o direito de procurar dentro do site fica muito fácil de alcançar altas pontuações no site, visto que existem muitas perguntas nesta categoria que estão na internet, nada contra mais sempre achei que a pontuação era de acordo com a quantidade de questões que você responderia as dúvidas. mais e bom saber porque quando eu localizar alguma coisa que está na internet e não está no site eu posso postar nesta categoria.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, entendo o seu ponto de vista, acredito que você está certo, mais o site está cheio de perguntas muito ruins e muitas não recebem nenhum voto para serem fechadas, em alguns casos são fechadas após alguém postar uma resposta.

Comment: Olá @Harry. Eu não falei nada de "altas reputações", estou falando do sistema do score servir para indicar que o conteúdo é de confiança, os pontos não servem só para alimentar egos, não, o propósito principal e ideal dos pontos é dizer que o conteúdo é bom ou ruim, principalmente das respostas. Espero que compreenda o papel desse tipo de postagem e qual o objetivo do site ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não tenho problemas com pontuação e ego, não me importo com isso, mais como falei, este tipo de pergunta no meu ponto de vista só serve para ganhar pontuação. Talvez esteja errado mais e o que penso sobre o assunto

Comment: @Harry eu não falei q vc tem esse problema, eu estou dizendo qual o propósito do score, que não tem haver com a sua pessoa, mas sim haver com as postagens de score alto, você reclamou de algo como se a preocupação de usuários como o Wallace fosse apenas o score, sendo que o objetivo da postagem e do score no site é avaliar o conteudo como sendo de confiança. É apenas isso.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### TL;DR

Não existe uma definição exata sobre o que é legado, mas o significado vai no sentido de um código antigo ou produzido com tecnologias já aposentadas ou técnicas antigas, quase sempre de difícil manutenção e controle.

Código legado, pode ser aquele código produzido em linguagem ou plataforma onde o fabricante já descontinuou o suporte de novas funcionalidades ou/e de segurança ou seja bugs existentes não serão corrigidos, o programador deve contornar essas situações ou criar um patch caso a plataforma/linguagem/framework seja open-source. A melhor alternativa seria isolar o código problemático e rescreve-lo com tecnologia moderna e integrá-lo ao sistema antigo.

Outra situação onde código pode ser considerado legado(no sentido de herança maldita) é quando o software já foi construído e após um tempo todos os membros originais do projeto já não trabalham mais nele, os 'novatos' encarregados não tem noção nenhuma do contexto do projeto, funcionamento interno da arquitetura etc normalmente não existe nenhuma documentação ou a existente já está totalmente defasada.

A definição do Michel Feathers, autor de [Trabalho Eficaz com Código Legado](http://www.grupoa.com.br/livros/engenharia-de-software-e-metodos-ageis/trabalho-eficaz-com-codigo-legado/9788582600320) é

> Código legado é aquele sem testes.

A frase acima é bem suspeita, já que um dos assuntos tratados no livro dele é de como testar código legado e adicionar testes unitários.

Fatores que vão matando o código ao longo do tempo são falta de manutenção preventiva ou refatoração, congelamento da plataforma por parte do cliente nenhuma atualização de versão pode ser feita devido a algum requisito bizarro do projeto ou política de homologação, mudanças drásticas na arquitetura, cada parte do software fica de um jeito isso também é conhecido como [lava flow](http://www.antipatterns.com/lavaflow.htm). Tudo isso combinado transforma qualquer alteração, complicada pois é difícil calcular efeitos colaterais e para piorar as vezes não existe ambiente de homologação então a alteração vai direto para produção.

**Relacionado:**

- [What makes code legacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/479596/1342547)
- [When is code “legacy”?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/94007/106391)

Comment: Ótimo esclarecimento! *Não existe uma definição exata* +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, obrigado pela edição, `path` é meio tenso mesmo kkk

Comment: Tirando as falhas de pontuação, excelente resposta. Parabéns.

Answer (score 44):

[image: Ensō, o símbolo da iluminação, força, elegância, o universo e o vazio]

<sub>Assim disse o Mestre Programador: *Que os programadores sejam muitos e os gerentes poucos - então todos serão produtivos.*</sub>

---

Diz a lenda que em uma longínqua província havia um monastério onde o Mestre Programador compartilhava seus ensinamentos. Um de seus diálogos foi a respeito de código legado.

'*Mestre*', perguntou o orgulhoso engenheiro da corte de Lao, '*Por que sistemas legados são usados? Geralmente quando lido com sistemas legados, sinto que lhes faltam Zen: Eles são como [karesansui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jardim_de_pedras_japon%C3%AAs)<sup>1</sup> que, em uma casa abandonada, são desfigurados pelo tempo e descuido. Esquecidos, se desconectam da natureza do negócio; não entendidos, impossibilitam o [feng shui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feng_shui).*'

'*A resposta é um reflexo do coração do engenheiro*', começou o mestre. Este então se levantou, no que foi seguido pelos discípulos que o acompanhavam naquela manhã de primavera onde as brumas da manhã ainda pairavam.

Iniciou então uma caminhada, que os levou colina acima até as bordas da floresta. Encontrando um lugar ao Sol na relva circundante onde o orvalho da manhã ainda persistia, virou-se e, sentando em uma pedra próxima, começou a observar a cidade à sua frente, cujos delicados telhados se estendiam como um punhado de jóias em uma bolsa da cor do jade.

À sua esquerda, beirando a estrada por onde os locais transitavam - aqui, uma mãe levando uma cesta de pães, um bebê à tiracolo; ali, um samurai com o passo decidido de alguém em uma importante missão dada por seu *daiymio* - , um pilar de madeira se erguia, decorados com motivos xintoístas e um um poema em estilo *haiku*:

> くもとへだつともかやかりのいきわかれ
>   *Nuvens nos separam - o tempo de partir chegou. O ganso selvagem alça vôo.*<sup>2</sup>

'*Esta é a quarta encarnação desta cidade*', disse o mestre, retornando ao assunto. '*Antes do nome atual, outros foram utilizados: outros engenheiros, do topo desta ravina, observaram o espaço à sua frente - outras construções, outras pessoas, outros tempos. Os engenheiros que ergueram aquele pilar já se foram a muito tempo; sua arte é agora apreciada em outros lugares, ou se retiraram dos prazeres do mundo.*

*Incêndios varreram as construções de madeira e bambu; dignatários da corte mudaram a residência oficial de endereço, tamanho, cor, formato e objetivo; o forte que foi construído à época da guerra foi convertido em um armazém.*

*Entretanto o poço de pedra na praça central é o mesmo - porque seu propósito é claro, sua implementação simples, e sua função perfeitamente observada. Está é uma das razões.*

*A mansão abandonada na floresta, também antiga, possui uma outra razão de ser. Lendas dizem que um [yōkai](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%8Dkai) a habita; soldados evitam suas redondezas, e mães a utilizam para conter a curiosidade de sua própria prole com histórias de crianças desaparecidas.*

*A cidade à nossa frente é como um tecido de fibras de várias épocas, em uma trama que conta, ao mesmo tempo, as estórias do velho e do novo. O Zen persiste não em aspectos individuais, mas sim em seu dia-a-dia, na vida que habita suas ruas de variadas larguras.*

*A natureza dos sistemas legados é, de maneira similar, oriunda ou do respeito pela funcionalidade ou pelo medo das consequências de se lidar com o desconhecido.*'

Porém o engenheiro se mostrava insatisfeito com a resposta. '*Mas seria isso o ideal, Mestre? Recentemente retornei de Edo, e a cidade se erguia magnífica - todos os prédios novos, seus vernizes reluzindo ao sol.*'

O mestre então lhe respondeu: '*Nem todas as cidades possuem cofres tão cheios quanto o Imperador, que pode se dar ao luxo de reconstruir uma cidade a seu bel-prazer. O que seria Zen, neste caso? Onde estaria o balanço entre vontade, objetivo e realização? Não estaria a cena à sua frente perfeitamente em balanço?*'

O mestre e seus seguidores continuaram admirando a cidade e seu burburinho. Após um alguns minutos de contemplação, o engenheiro sorriu. Ele tinha aceitado a natureza do argumento; com seus novos olhos, à sua frente, a pequena cidade reluzia em perfeito equilíbrio no orvalho da manhã.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Jardim de pedras japonês.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup>[Matsuo Bashō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsuo_Bash%C5%8D), 1671</sub>

Comment: Simplesmente poético!

Comment: 雲 と へ だつ 友 か や 雁 の 生き 別れ
Kumo-to-ê-datsu tomo-ka, ya-kari-no iki-wakarê.

OnoSendai acho que cortou o く de kumo(nuvem) no início da sua frase em hiraganá.
Resumo da historinha: -Engenheiro: Por que sistemas legados são usados? -Mestre Zen: Porque nem toda empresa tem grana pra fazer um sistema novo toda vez que o sistema começa a ficar antigo.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre Sim, essa seria a versão TL;DR. ;) Quanto à citação, você está certo! Obrigado pela correção. =)

Comment: muito boa, ganho um upvote só pela cultura...

Answer (score 31):

É um código que já estava presente antes do código que se pretende escrever agora e está relacionado com o código que se pretende escrever agora, mas não foi escrito prevendo esta relação.

De maneira geral, o código legado não possui um mecanismo de integração fácil ou óbvio com este código que se pretende escrever agora.

Expressões relacionadas: **aplicações legadas** ou **sistemas legados**. O conceito é o mesmo: você precisa escrever novas aplicações que de algum modo se relacionam com estas que já estavam lá (seja se integrando com elas ou substituindo-as).

## Código legado é código ultrapassado?

Não necessariamente, mas geralmente sim, pois a expressão têm lugar justamente quando se trata dos desafios de integração ou de substituição do legado.

Se precisamos substituir, ou se em vez de expandir o existente vamos integrar algor novo, então é provável que o que está lá (o "legado") seja "ultrapassado".

É importante notar que "ultrapassado", ou que precisa ser substituído ou que não pode ser expandido, nem sempre significa que é ruim.

Em outras palavras, **o legado nem sempre é de má qualidade ou mal feito**. Existem vários outros motivos para substituir uma ferramenta ou usar novas em integração com ela em vez de expandi-la.

Comment: Muito comum ver isso no PHP :) +1

Comment: ps: não fui eu quem negativou :p +1

Answer (score 3):

Isso é uma definição de minha autoria: "Código legado é aquele que é herdado e você não tem confiança suficiente para modificá-lo." Todo o código criado tem potencial de virar legado, sim. Mas nem todo o código criado vira legado. No livro "Como ser um programador melhor", Goodliffe explica se um código não tiver manutenção, tende a sumir da empresa, seja por outra ferramenta interna, seja por software de fornecedor. Essa também pode ser uma boa definição.

Answer (score 1):

> Legado.
>
> s.m. O que é passado às gerações que se seguem.

Quando você entra numa empresa, denomina-se de *código legado*  todo código que você deverá dar manutenção e cujo qual não houve sua participação no desenvolvimento inicial. Ele pode ter sido escrito por programadores que não fazem mais parte do quadro de funcionários da empresa ou programadores mais antigos na equipe que agora dedicarão seu tempo a outros projetos.

Answer (score -2):

Código legado é aquele implementado em parte ou em totalidade usando alguma tecnologia antiga em relação a atualidade tecnológica.
Esta é a minha definição. 
Uma das razões que vejo para a existência desse tipo de codigo é a limitação do **sistema computacional** onde o *projeto* está rodando.