# Qual é a diferença entre as versões stable e legacy do jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, versionamento

Fui baixar JQuery UI e percebi que tem duas opções, uma chamada stable e outra legacy, gostaria de saber a diferença.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A versão legado (legacy) é uma versão mais antiga, mas que alguém ainda possa precisar. No caso do jQuery UI ainda tem até suporte para ela. Às vezes há conflitos de dependências (nesse caso o próprio jQuery), por isso essa versão ainda é liberada.

- [O que é um código legado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107722/o-que-%C3%A9-um-c%C3%B3digo-legado)

A versão estável (stable) é o release mais novo, suportado e estável do jQuery UI. Tenha certeza que na versão mais recente, muitos bugs foram corrigidos, algumas funcionalidades novas apareceram e novos bugs surgiram :P