# Qual a diferença entre client-server e three-tiers?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, projeto-de-software, sistemas-distribuídos

No capítulo de Software Design ([SWEBOK](https://www.computer.org/education/bodies-of-knowledge/software-engineering)) ao falar sobre estilos de arquitetura são citados client-server e three-tiers:

> Various authors have identified a number of major **architectural styles**: 
>   distributed systems (for example, client-server, **three-tiers**)
>   [...]

Não compreendo bem a diferença entre esses estilos arquiteturais. Além disso, parece que esses estilos estão fora do escopo de *software design*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Cliente-servidor

O cliente-servidor é um modelo de duas camadas onde geralmente tem um componente de software que interage com o usuário ou opera algo na frente mais visível de um sistema, enquanto que o servidor é responsável por fazer o trabalho mais específico em outra parte fisicamente separada.

Um exemplo fácil é o que encontramos na web onde você tem o *browser* agindo como cliente e o servidor HTTP obviamente agindo como servidor, então um deles inicia a ação toda requisitando algo ao servidor que sabe o que fazer com aquela requisição e entrega o resultado para o cliente operar como achar melhor, no caso ele renderiza uma página HTML e coisas do gênero.

Outro exemplo que é muito citado e que não deixa de ser cliente-servidor, mas a forma como usam é um pouco equivocada é a aplicação desktop que acessa um outro serviço que é um banco de dados, então o primeiro é o cliente e o DB seria o servidor. Acho isso um erro porque o banco de dados não faz parte da sua arquitetura então até tem um cliente e um servidor, mas **o seu** sistema não pode ser classificado assim, a solução como um todo até é um *client-server*.

É comum que cada uma dessas duas partes esteja em máquinas separadas na mesma rede ou em outra, mas nada impede que esteja na mesma, tem vários casos assim, só não costuma ser tão visível. De uma certa forma todo consumo de serviços do sistema operacional é assim sempre tem sua aplicação como cliente e o sistema operacional é o servidor. É importante notar isto porque a invisibilidade do hardware dá a impressão de ser uma coisa só, mas só o fato do software ser separado já indica que tem um serviço sendo consumido por um cliente.

É menos comum as pessoas verem isso (o que não quer dizer que seja incomum existir) mas existem arquiteturas cliente-servidor diferentes, por exemplo um sistema de janelas onde o que você vê é o cliente, mas o processamento mais interno é feito por um outro componente bastante isolado que é o servidor, isto é interessante porque dá as vantagens citadas abaixo, o [X-Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) é um exemplo.

Este tip ode arquitetura pode dar mais segurança, escalabilidade, flexibilidade (pode trocar componentes, acessar remotamente, interoperabilidade), e em alguns casos mais performance (apesar de um certo *overhead* que isto gera), além de poder simplificar o funcionamento, pelo menos em um certo ponto de vista. NO contexto da pergunta a distribuição se torna simples já que tem uma separação clara de cada parte.

O ponto fundamental é que tenha um requisitante e um entregador de resultados.

## 3 camadas

Quando você adiciona um componente no meio para intermediar o processo, em geral chamado de *middleware* você tem a arquitetura de 3 camadas. Este *middleware* pode delegar para outra camada certas tarefas, coordenando esse trabalho. Em geral aumenta a complexidade e nem sempre o ganho é óbvio, por isso é menos comum encontrar este tipo de arquitetura. Hoje em dia ou se faz o cliente-servidor puro ou opta-se por algo mais descentralizado acessando o que seria uma terceira camada diretamente pelo cliente distribuindo ainda mais o trabalho.

Algumas pessoas consideram que se você tiver um cliente, um servidor de aplicação e um banco de dados você tem 3 camadas, novamente eu acho um erro, mas informalmente pode ser aceitável. Então algumas pessoas consideram que um sistema típico web é assim já que ele tem o *browser*, o servidor HTTP e o banco de dados. Pelo menos é uma forma simples de entender.

## Confusão

Estas arquiteturas não devem ser usadas para organizar o desenvolvimento.

Só tome cuidado com 3 *tiers* e 3 *layers*, que em geral traduzimos ambos para 3 camadas.

O primeiro é um padrão de arquitetura dos componentes de software onde é feito 3 *deploys* separados e por isso ele é comparável com o *client-server* e pode ser distribuído, dentro do contexto da pergunta.

O segundo é um padrão de organização de código, é algo mais interno e não precisa gerar componentes diferentes de software. É comum ter os 3 apenas no servidor, ou apenas no cliente ou até apenas no *middleware* (menos comum porque este tende a ser um "guarda de trânsito" da solução, por isso ele não é um padrão de distribuição que é citado no SWEBOK (o contexto dele deixa mais claro a separação). Não é comum se falar em 3 *tiers* por isso se você pesquisa vai achar mais sobre 3 *layers*.

O MVC é uma forma conhecida de 3 camadas nesse sentido. Este é um caso para organizar o desenvolvimento.

Trechos do SWEBOK que dão mais contexto:

> A distributed system is a collection of physically separate, possibly  heterogeneous computer systems that are networked to provide the users with access  to the various resources that the system maintains. Construction of distributed software is distinguished from traditional software construction by issues such as parallelism, communication, and fault tolerance. Distributed programming typically falls into one of several basic architectural categories: client-server, 3-tier architecture, n-tier architecture, distributed objects, loose coupling, or tight coupling algorithm selection—influences an execution speed and size.

Se o trecho fosse copiado por completo na pergunta talvez desse mais contexto que são itens de separação física já que 3 exemplos desambíguam mais:

> Distributed systems (for example, client-server, three-tiers, broker)

Para contexto o *broker* é uma forma de *middleware* usada em [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) (Service-oriented architecture), algo que vem sendo suplantado por microsserviços (pra mim ambos estão equivocados em quase todos os cenários)

#### Middleware

> Middleware is a broad classification for software that provides services above the operating system layer yet below the application program layer. Middleware can provide runtime containers for software components to provide message passing,  persistence, and a transparent location across a network. Middleware can be viewed as a connector between the components that use the middleware. Modern message-oriented middleware usually provides an Enterprise Service Bus (ESB), which supports service-oriented interaction and communication between multiple software applications.

[Fonte](https://www.computer.org/education/bodies-of-knowledge/software-engineering).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não tive acesso prévio ao SWEBOK, isso pode ter ocasionado a confusão bem explicitada por você. Vou estudar um tanto mais e dar uma revisada na minha resposta. E no meio tempo ler sua resposta atualizada =D

Answer (score 5):

### 3 Layers

Tomando por base a [Presentation Domain Data Layer](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html), do Fowler, uma aplicação de 3 camadas consiste de:

- apresentação
- negócio
- acesso a recursos/dados

Com essa arquitetura, foca-se na informação a ser renderizada/apresentada, na informação a ser operada e na informação a ser salva/resgatada.

> Note que o banco de dados *não faz parte* dessa arquitetura, mas sim a camada de *acesso ao banco*.

Fowler considera e defende (de maneira geral) o uso dessa arquitetura por uma questão simples: escopo de atenção. A equipe que está na camada de apresentação não está muito preocupada com o que está acontecendo na camada de negócio, então para ela basta saber como exibir os dados fornecidos através de uma API previamente determinada.

A equipe de negócios não vai precisar se preocupar em como a informação será exibida, nem tampouco como ela será persistida/resgatada, focando sua atenção meramente em manipular a informação corretamente e dar o resultado correto. As pessoas dessa equipe precisam ter uma API conhecida para fazer a requisição de recursos ou para mandar persisti-los, e só precisam saber disso da camada de recursos/dados.

A equipe da camada de persistência não precisa se preocupar se os cálculos serão feitos da maneira correta, apenas saber como montar os dados requisitados ou salvá-los. A opção de salvar em um banco embarcado temporariamente, manter em memória ou mesmo enviar ao banco de dados perene é uma preocupação dessa camada.

Do próprio Fowler, descrevendo o comportamento de uma *euquipe* trabalhando nessas 3 camadas (tradução livre):

> Quando estou trabalhando na [camada de] apresentação eu consigo focar no comportamento de UI, tratando qualquer dado a ser mostrado ou atualizado como aparecendo magicamente através de chamadas de funções. Ao separar esses elementos eu afunilo o escopo do meu pensamento em cada peça, p que torna mais fácil para mim dar continuidade no que preciso fazer.

Mesmo havendo ocasionalmente algum desenvolvimento *cross-section* (que corte por múltiplas camadas), o desenvolvimento incremental se torna mais natural. Imagina que você está fazendo um aplicativo de vendas e, quando está fazendo a interface, se depara com "puts, esqueci o ICMS-ST". Assim, a camada de apresentação deixa uma caixetinha pronta para receber um dado arbitrário com o valor desse imposto (que eventualmente modifica o valor de **compra** da mercadoria, mas não modifica o de **venda**). Então, com isso pronto, ele pode se preocupar em resgatar do banco corretamente as alíquotas desse imposto e seu valor de pauta, para então, na camada de negócio, decidir se os dados estão favoráveis a usar alíquota ou pauta e fazer os cálculos pertinentes, entregando para a camada de apresentação um dado redondinho.

---

Note que esse tipo de arquitetura de 3 camadas **não impõe** onde esse processamento deve ocorrer. Por exemplo, onde trabalho, usamos GWT. Escrevemos em Java e em um dialeto de XML chamado de `ui.xml` a camada de apresentação, e o GWT magicamente transforma isso em JavaScript e envia para a o cliente. A camada de negócio está normalmente em uma dependência a parte, que internamente denominamos de *núcleo* do sistema.

> Se quiser ler mais, [escrevi um artigo no Medium](https://link.medium.com/QPGDHAiZoZ) que trata disso também

O núcleo é todo escrito em Java e feito para rodar como Java Web, compatível (na parte estritamente necessária) com a serialização do GWT e compatível com TotalCross.

> Estamos deixando-o viável para Android também, em breve escreverei um artigo sobre o assunto

Além do núcleo, onde ocorrem as validações de regras de negócio, temos também uma camada que chamamos de `DAO` (ou `I-DAO`, existindo uma pseudocamada `M-DAO`) por força do hábito. Essa camada, implementada pela aplicação que chama o núcleo, se preocupa apenas em montar os dados para dá-los ao núcleo ou em salvar os dados advindos do núcleo. A única coisa que importa para o núcleo é que ele consiga chamar através do Java e que sejam métodos síncronos (escolha essa questionável, mas não havia muito suporte para assincronia no TotalCross).

Na implementação TotalCross dessa camada, ela é basicamente escrita em Java com TCDBC (tipo o JDBC, mas do TotalCross; similares demais, mas tem algumas diferenças que exigem bastante atenção). Já na implementação Java Web (irrelevante ser GWT ou não), temos que o `DAO` escrito em Java mastiga os dados para chamar o MyBatis de maneira otimizada, sem as consultas escritas no jeito MyBatis de ser que mistura um dialeto de XML e "texto" em SQL dentro das tags. Em algumas vezes é preferível nessa camada transformar o objeto de negócio em outro de transporte de dados que seja mais fácil de manipular com o MyBatis, assim como recuperar objetos de transporte para montá-los corretamente após chamar o banco.

Essa separação permitiu um trabalho muito mais otimizado da equipe, principalmente na parte GWT. A parte GWT foi reescrita do zero, abandonando totalmente a parte GWT antiga para poder atualizar tecnologia (como o MyBatis, que antes era o iBatis) e removendo da camada de apresentação as regras de negócio. O código legado em GWT ainda fazia muita regra de negócio na camada de apresentação.

Na parte TotalCross, entretanto, não houve uma reescrita total. Na verdade, dessa parte foi extraído o núcleo de maneira experimental e exploratória e fomos adaptando aos poucos algumas partes extraídas para se comunicar com o núcleo, mas pontualmente e com toda a carga de um gigante código legado nas costas. Ainda há muita regra de negócio nas camadas que deveriam se preocupar apenas com apresentação dos dados, principalmente em telas de pouca customização e com baixa incidência de bugs reportados.

> [Código legado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185404/64969) e a parte "desarmônica" da cidade.

Temos outra "aplicação" no trabalho que, na verdade, não há regra de negócio. É apenas a implementação de um protocolo de comunicação desenhado para atender as limitações fornecidas pelo TotalCross né época, o protocolo TJ.

A implementação desse protocolo consiste de um cliente e um servidor, porém não determina a função de cada um. Temos o caso que ambos, cliente e servidor, são capazes de escrever e ler nesse protocolo. Outros casos em que só acontece a escrita, outros em que só acontece a leitura.

No envio de dados, a aplicação é composta apenas de uma fina camada de acesso ao banco para recuperar as informações a serem enviadas e um apresentador, que irá envelopar o `ResultSet` em um JSON. No recebimento de dados, que pelo protocolo TJ precisa ser *muito* complacente, apenas há a leitura do que foi apresentado e envia para o banco de dados o *upsert* ou *delete* da linha correspondente, havendo portanto a necessidade de se implementar uma fina camada de introspecção das tabelas e de uma camada de montagem do *upsert*.

Assim, essas "aplicações" que implementam o envio do TJ podem ser analisadas através das 3 camadas, onde só há preocupação com apresentação e resgate. A implementação do recebimento, por sua vez, não tem apresentação de dados, apenas o *parse* (talvez alguém considere camada de negócio?) e persistência.

---

### Client-server

A arquitetura **cliente-servidor** é independente da arquitetura de 3 camadas. Na arquitetura cliente-servidor tradicional, você tem uma aplicação que está escutando (o servidor) e outra que eventualmente faz uma requisição.

Nessa arquitetura, quem indica que deseja comunicação é o **cliente**. Um servidor só é capaz de enviar algum dado ao cliente quando ele está conectado.

O modelo HTTP 1.0 é um exemplo de arquitetura cliente-servidor, onde o cliente (costumeiramente o browser) pede um recurso (uma página web) para o servidor. Quando termina a comunicação, os dois se despedem e tchau, só se houver outra requisição do cliente para poder enviar dados.

Mas nem toda comunicação cliente-servidor precisa ser assim, apenas o cliente empurrando dados. O SSH também é cliente-servidor, e nesse caso o comando `top`, quando digitado do terminal do cliente, inicia o executável `top` que fica constantemente atualizando o cliente com as informações de consumo de recursos da máquina onde está o servidor. O `watch` também causa o servidor enviar dados sem precisar ser incomodado explicitamente pelo cliente.

No meu trabalho, viramos mais fortemente a arquitetura cliente-servidor justamente nas aplicações que trabalham com o protocolo TJ. Temos um cliente escrito em ADVPL para rodar em ERPs Protheus capaz de apresentar os dados no formato TJ, assim como também de ler as informações e decidir como persisti-las no Protheus. Mas o nosso servidor foi escrito *independente do cliente*, aceitando ser plugado por outros ERPs, testável via requisição HTTP.

Comment: Editei a minha, dá uma olhada :)

Answer (score 0):

Cliente/Servidor é um "modelo" onde há quem desempenha o papel de cliente e há quem desempenha o papel de servidor em um dado relacionamento. E estes papéis podem variar conforme o relacionamento. Por exemplo, o servidor (quem oferece um determinado serviço), também pode desempenhar o papel de cliente em outro relacionamento, possivelmente para atender a requisição dos seus clientes. Vale consultar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model.

Por outro lado, quando se fala em *tiers*, em geral, está-se falando em elementos físicos distintos, onde cada um deles executa um conjunto de processos. Novamente, a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) pode fornecer alguma orientação.

Convém observar que estes nomes não são elementos "essenciais" de um problema ou solução. Curiosamente, nem mesmo fazem parte do "Aurélio da Engenharia de Software" (norma ISO/IEC/IEEE 24765:2017). Isto não significa que não são relevantes, servem para nossa comunicação.