# Qual a relação de arquitetura de software e design patterns?

Tags: terminologia, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software

Qual a diferença e semelhanças entre arquitetura de software e *design pattern*? Eu dei uma pesquisada no Wikipédia e pareceram bem diferentes:

> Arquitetura Modelo-Visão-Controlador (do inglês: Model-View-Controller
>   - MVC) é um padrão de arquitetura de software (não confundir com design pattern)

E aqui diz um pouco ao contrário da citação acima:

> Já o MVC é um *design pattern*, ou padrão de projeto, que é utilizado
>   para organizar a aplicação em camadas lógicas para facilitar a
>   manutenção de um sistema, ou seja, o sistema é dividido em diversos
>   pacotes dentro de uma mesma solução para que o desenvolvimento do
>   mesmo seja melhor interpretado.

Como esse dois conceitos (se eu posso chamá-los assim) se relacionam no nosso dia a dia?

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC), [ProfissionalTI](https://www.profissionaisti.com.br/2015/04/arquitetura-de-sistemas-x-design-pattern/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nunca leia a Wikipedia em português, ela é cheia de erros e não deixam você consertar em grande parte das vezes (a versão em inglês estava errada até esses dias também, quem sabe agora deixem mudar). Este caso nem é grave porque realmente tem definições um tanto controversas por aí. [A versão em inglês fala que é um padrão de projeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) mesmo e é suportado pelo Uncle Bob que alguns juram que é deus na área (eu não acho), segundo ele o criador do MVC, seu amigo, disse que é um DP.

Se formos olhar [o que é arquitetura de software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture) vemos que ela engloba coisas que vão além do que o MVC faz, especialmente o MVC não tem interação externa, nenhum componente externo precisa sequer saber que você usou MVC. ME parece que este é o ponto principal para não definir o MVC como arquitetura.

Arquitetura está virando algo parecido com OOP, as pessoas estão vendo os outros falarem disso e querem entrar na turma, então tudo vira OOP, tudo vira arquitetura, mas também tudo vira *design pattern* que é outra coisa de moda, e tem hora que o pessoal nem sabe qual nome escolher porque não é definido de forma pensada, é só o que ela acredita ser. O fato das pessoas usarem algo (ou pelo menos falarem que usam) que elas nem entendem o que é já diz muita coisa...

Então não há relação direta, é só erro de definição, como quase tudo o que tem na internet hoje em dia. Um dos textos *linkados* faz confusão quando tenta explicar, eu já falei sobre o assunto em [Qual a diferença entre client-server e three-tiers?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405299/101), camadas nada tem a ver com uma coisa outra, camadas são camadas, como elas são usadas definirá o que elas são. Uma das vantagens do inglês é que ele tem termos diferentes para definir o que é cada tipo de camada que chamamos em português, aí muita gente se perde na tradução.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Antigamente a Wiki.PT dizia que MVC era um design pattern e a Wiki.EN que era um padrão arquitetural. Atualmente elas inverteram as definições. Vai entender. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Procurei no histórico e não achei isso, achei que era sinônimo, o que também não, depois colocaram que era para não confundir. Em inglês mudou esses dias.

Comment: Que coisa, podia jurar que lá falava isso. Fiz confusão.

Answer (score 4):

Arquitetura de Software é um termo bem ambíguo. Provavelmente se você for para a pessoa mais sênior de qualquer equipe e perguntar "Qual a arquitetura do seu software?" ela vai te responder com outra pergunta, pedindo mais informações do que você realmente deseja saber:

1. Quer entender qual a estrutura do software como um todo?
2. Quer entender como o software se relaciona com o ambiente e outros componentes?
3. Quer entender como organizamos internamente o código?

Entre outras. Por isto, não me espanta você ler tantas definições diferentes pela Internet.

A maioria das "arquiteturas" são inspiradas, de alguma forma, em outros sistemas que também resolvem problemas parecidos. Este conceito é muito similar a definição de Design Pattern, que é entendido como *uma solução comum para um problema comum em determinado contexto*.

Porém, o termo Design Pattern está normalmente relacionado a soluções prontas e **pontuais** no nível de código (*Abstract Factory*, *Builder*, etc). Dentro **deste escopo**, podemos partir da definição que a Arquitetura de um Software nada mais que é um conjunto de *patterns* juntos.

O MVC, por ser um pattern mais abrangente dentro do software, normalmente é conhecido como padrão de arquitetura, mas poderia ser perfeitamente definido como um Design Pattern também ao meu ver.

No mais, recomendo a leitura [este artigo da IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/feb06/eeles/index.html) que explica muito bem esta confusão toda com o significa de arquitetura.